# Zeitgeist Command Line Query Client

Tags: linux, zeitgeist

[Zeitgeist for Linux](http://zeitgeist-project.com) is an intelligent operating system activity log that stores various information in a database, like latest opened files, latest launched programs, etc.

I was curious to know if there exist any command line clients for querying the database?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a command line client. But you can achieve this in two ways:

1. The database file `~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite`.
2. There is a Python API. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://bloc.eurion.net/archives/2012/zeitgeist-python-api-tutorial/).

Comment: It's been a while and I had forgotten about it. Amazing ! Thanks.